# How do I remove car radio?

Tags: audio

Well I just suffered 100% damage on my Daewoo Lanos (thank God nobody got seriously injured)  and I want to remove as much usable components from it as I can before I sell it. One of them is Sony CDX-GT500 radio.

So what kind of tools do I need to remove it and what would be the procedure? I don't have its manual, so I can't check the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is anything like the Sony radio I have, it it held in by a pair of sprung clips, one either side of the radio. It then comes with a set of removal tools consisting of a pair of flat blades (although you could use any suitable thin, stiff flat object such as a metal ruler). To remove it you slide these blades down the sides of the radio, and apply an outward pressure to unlatch the clips, then withdraw the unit.

The mounting cage can then be removed from the dash by un-bending the small tabs that hold it in position - these should be obvious once the radio is out.

Comment: I selected this answer because in my case it was closer to the situation I found in my car. The other one is good too.

Answer (score 1):

Not know what your center console looks like, you likely need to remove the trim around the radio. Trim is normally popped in with clips, and can be removed easily in most cases. The radio can be held in with either clips, or screws.

Added:
[How to remove a Daewoo Lanos car stereo - (Most Models)](http://www.fitaudio.com/?View=entry&EntryID=88)